# Typecasting in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm new to SML, and am using the SMLNJ dialect.

For some purpose I have been trying to typecast 3 to 3.0 (int to real).

Could not find a way out. How can I do this? How can I convert between types?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer.
You just type `real(2)` for instance, to convert 2 (int) to 2.0 (real).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the function `real` (or `Real.fromInt`) to convert an `int` to a `real`.

For further information you can see a list of functions available in the Top-level environment [here](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/top-level-chapter.html#section%3asec%3atop-level-env) and an overview of the Basis library [here](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/overview.html).

Comment: Great, I think this is profound ;). int and real is 2 different type and SML does not convert from type 'int' to 'real'.

Answer (score 7):

SML doesn't have typecasts. Any mapping between types needs to be done through functions.

`real(3)` looks and behaves much like a C-style typecast, but `real: int -> real` is just another function in the standard basis. `int(3.0)`, on the other hand, doesn't work, because the `int` function doesn't exist.

In general, when you need to convert between types, you'd just dig through the library for an appropriate function. In the `real -> int` case, just searching for "real -> int" in the [top level environment](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/top-level-chapter.html) turns up `round`, `trunc`, `floor` and `ceil`.